# Netsuite transaction column field recalculate

Tags: netsuite

I created a new transaction column field called Margin and I added it to sales orders. I wrote a script to calculate margin based on the item fields however if you go back to edit the values, the script doesn't recalculate. How do I get it to recalculate when a user edits the values?

```
function postSourcing(type, name){
    if(name == 'item'){
    var unitPrice = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','rate');
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Price', + unitPrice);
    var itemid = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item');
    var avgCost = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','lastpurchaseprice');
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Cost', + avgCost);

   var marginCalc = Math.round((((unitPrice - avgCost)/unitPrice)*100) * 10)/10;
   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Margin', + marginCalc);
   nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcol9', marginCalc);
   avgCost = Math.round(avgCost * 100)/100;
   nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','lastpurchaseprice', avgCost);


   var dollarPro = unitPrice - avgCost;
   nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcoldollarprofit', dollarPro);

   var itemQty = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity');
   var extDollar = dollarPro * itemQty;
   nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcolextdollarprofit',extDollar);
   nlapiCommitLineItem('item');


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, on the postSourcing event, you have two parameters: type is the internal id of the sublist that changed, and name is the internal id of the field that changed.

So in the code you pasted above:

```
function postSourcing(type, name){
if(name == 'item'){
```

You are only triggering this code to run when the 'item' field in the item sublist changes. You have two choices: 
add the unit price and unit cost fields to your 'if' statement

```
if(name == 'item' || name == 'lastpurchaseprice' || name == 'rate')
```

or have it run on the entire item list

```
if(type == 'item')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that a change to the `item` field is firing a Post-Sourcing event? Do you see your log messages? You could try moving to Field Changed event instead just to see if that works. You could also try the Recalc event.

As an aside, I would recommend console logging on the client side instead of nlapi logging for performance reasons. Logging back to NetSuite forces an HTTP request and record creation for each log statement.

Comment: It only seems to work as a post source event. It actually works if you don't edit anything but that is the issue. If you try to change the price the values stays the same.

Comment: If you want the script to execute when you edit the price, you need to add a function for the field change event.

Comment: @RustyShackles is correct. Right now, you only have a post-sourcing event that you've restricted to only run when the `item` field changes. If there are other fields that you need to respond to, you will need to add the appropriate field IDs to either a Post-Sourcing or a Field Changed event handler, something like `function fieldChanged(type, name) { if (name == 'price' || name == 'rate' || name == 'quantity) { // Recalculate margins here }` I would recommend extracting your recalculation logic into its own function, and simply calling that function on the appropriate events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with. Thanks everyone for the tips! This is now working 100%. I hope this will be able to help anyone else who is trying to do the same thing or something similar.

```
/* 
* Author: Laura Micek
* Date: 10/20/14
* Purpose: Populates the margin, $ profit and ext. $ profit custom fields on various transaction    forms.
* Uses a postsource event for the initial values and the field change event for the recalculation of values.
*/

function postSourcing(type, name) {

if(type == 'item') {

    var unitPrice = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','rate');
    var avgCost = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','lastpurchaseprice');

    /* calculates margin by subtracting average cost from unit price and then dividing by average cost. 
     * It is then multiplied by 100 to get the percent. Used Math.round to round to one decimal place. */
    var marginCalc = Math.round((((unitPrice - avgCost)/unitPrice)*100) * 10)/10;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcol9', marginCalc);
    avgCost = Math.round(avgCost * 100)/100;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','lastpurchaseprice', avgCost);

    var dollarPro = unitPrice - avgCost;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcoldollarprofit', dollarPro);

    var itemQty = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity');
    var extDollar = dollarPro * itemQty;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcolextdollarprofit',extDollar);

    }

}

function reCalc(type, name) {

/*intialized the unit price here so that I could check if it was above zero.
 If you don't check, it will try to recalculate based on zero and you will
 get a invalid percent error*/
var unitPrice = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','rate');

//check if quantity was updated
if(name == 'quantity') {
    var unitPrice = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','rate');
    var avgCost = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','lastpurchaseprice');

    var dollarPro = unitPrice - avgCost;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcoldollarprofit', dollarPro);

    var itemQty = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity');
    var extDollar = dollarPro * itemQty;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcolextdollarprofit',extDollar);
}

//checks if the unit price was change and if the price is greater than zero
if(name == 'rate' && unitPrice > 0 ) {
    unitPrice = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','rate');
    var avgCost = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','lastpurchaseprice');

    /* calculates margin by subtracting average cost from unit price and then dividing by average cost. 
     * It is then multiplied by 100 to get the percent. Used Math.round to round to one decimal place. */
    var marginCalc = Math.round((((unitPrice - avgCost)/unitPrice)*100) * 10)/10;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcol9', marginCalc);
    avgCost = Math.round(avgCost * 100)/100;
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','lastpurchaseprice', avgCost);  
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you deploy the script only to the transaction forms you added the fields to!